# Decryption of password stored by Google Chrome browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, sqlite, qt

I have read that it is possible to  decrypt the password stored in Chrome on the same machine and by the same user that encrypted it in the first place.

Can anyone please give me the example of this?

Im fetching **Login data** from google chrome browser at path **D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default**
Im posting my code below:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QVariant>
#include<WinCrypt.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create database.
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "Connection");
    db.setDatabaseName("D:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User     Data/Default/login data");
    if (!db.open()) {
        printf("Error occurred opening the database.");
        printf("%s.", (db.lastError().text()));
        return -1;
    }
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare("SELECT username_value FROM logins");
    if (!query.exec()) {
        printf("Error occurred querying.");
        printf("%s.", (db.lastError().text()));
        return -1;
    }
    while (query.next()) {
        printf("password = %s",(query.value(0).toString()));
             /***NEED HELP***/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In  **/*** NEED HELP***/**  for portion i want to write password decryption function
i.e.

```
 DATA_BLOB DataOut;
 DATA_BLOB DataVerify;
 if (CryptUnprotectData(
        &DataOut,
        &pDescrOut,
        NULL,                 // Optional entropy
        NULL,                 // Reserved
        0,        // Optional PromptStruct
        0,
        &DataVerify))
  {
        printf("The decrypted data is: %s\n", DataVerify.pbData);
        printf("The description of the data was: %S\n",pDescrOut);
  }
```

But I'm unable to convert password_value fetched from SQLLite database to DATA_BLOB type.

Comment: Is this the start of your malicious software?

Comment: Hope this is just a fun hack project. You only need to convert your string to byte array.. From MSDN doc: typedef struct DATA_BLOB {
  DWORD cbData;
  BYTE  *pbData;
}